# iptables rule to bridge the gap between a tunnel (SSH/SOCKS) and the local KVM interface for the guest?

Tags: ssh, iptables

### Definitions

- `host` = 172.16.1.155 is a public IP (changed it using `sed` to be consistent).
- `guest` = 192.168.122.10 is the IP of a virtual machine running on the physical machine whose IP is 172.16.1.155.

### Situation

I have the following rules (dumped with `iptables-save` and filtered) for the two hosts in question (plus all required to understand the context):

```
*filter
-A INPUT -d 172.16.1.155/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i _+ -o _+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i _+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.10/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j LOG
-A FORWARD -j DROP
COMMIT
*nat
-A PREROUTING -d 172.16.1.155/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.10
COMMIT
```

The rules ensure that any request from the outside world to the public IP of `host` will actually end up in `guest`. All of that works fine and as intended. There are many more rules, but they affect only the other guests or have unrelated purposes. All interfaces for the guests start with an underscore so I can conveniently use `_+` to match the interface names in the above rules.

The virtual machines are all KVM guests. The name of the bridge interface is `virbr0`. Each virtual machine with an external IP address has an interface named after it but prepended with an underscore (so guest `foo` would have the interface `_foo`).

Additionally KVM creates a `vnetX` (`X` being a number) interface per guest.

The following routes are set w.r.t. the `host` and `guest` in question:

```
172.16.1.155    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
default         172.16.1.155    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

### Question

If I create a SOCKS proxy by SSH-ing into `host` (`ssh -D`) I cannot connect to `guest` via that proxy. First I thought that the reason was that the SOCKS proxy would probably use the `lo` interface (`tcpdump -i lo` confirms that) on the `host` side, so I added the following rule `iptables -I FORWARD -i lo -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j ACCEPT` (keep in mind that `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` accepts the input already), but that should already be covered by `-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.10/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j ACCEPT`. So I removed the rule again and tried the following NAT rule: `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.1/24 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.10` and subsequently its equivalent (for all practical purposes) `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i lo -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.10`. Neither gave me the result I wanted.

How can I bridge the gap in this scenario? And moreover, is my assumption valid that I can test whether the SOCKS proxy works by using `telnet 127.0.0.1 25`?

---

So I was adding the rule `iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/24 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.10` as suggested by mgorven. There is clearly a change in behavior here, but it's not yet entirely what I'm looking for.

Without that rule I get:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

with that rule I get:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PREROUTING chain is not traversed for packets originating from the host ([this diagram](http://xkr47.outerspace.dyndns.org/netfilter/packet_flow/packet_flow9.png) is useful for figuring out which chains a packet will traverse). You want to put those rules into the OUTPUT chain of the `nat` table.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Sounds logical, let me try it and then I'll accept or ask back. +1 for now.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your suggestion. Added what I tried to my question. Any ideas? I'm still puzzled. Clearly this is a step in the right direction but something is still missing.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Um, I wouldn't try to DNAT 127.0.0.1 to the VM. The loopback interface is kinda special so I doubt that that can work. DNAT the host's public IP to the VM and connect to the public IP through the SOCKS server.

Comment: i.e. move the rule from `PREROUTING` to `OUTPUT`?

Comment: @0xC0000022L No, you need the DNAT rule in both the PREROUTING chain (for packets from outside) *and* the OUTPUT chain (for packets from the host itself).

Comment: that's it. Now I also understand it a bit better, I think. Thanks for the link to the diagram, too.